# How to use @Transactional annotation in mybatis-spring?

Tags: java, database, spring, mybatis

I tried to use `@Transactional` annotation in `spring` and `mybatis` using `mybatis-spring` dependency. This is the service layer.

```
@Service
public class OracleService {

    @Autowired
    private TestMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,
                   rollbackFor = Exception.class,
                   value = "transactionManager")
    void insert1() {
        TestModel testModel = new TestModel(1, "title1", "content1");
        mapper.insert(testModel);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

As you can see, a `RuntimeException` is thrown out in `insert1()`, so the insert operation should fail. But in fact, it didn't. The record was inserted successfully. Why?

Here is my main method.

```
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext cxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        OracleService oracleService = cxt.getBean(OracleService.class);
        try {
            oracleService.insert1();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred!");
        }
    }
}
```

Spring configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.database.learn"/>

    <bean id="oracleDataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <property name="URL" value="OracleJdbcUrl"/>
        <property name="user" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="testMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.database.learn.TestMapper"/>
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

I used the following dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you added @EnableTransactionManagement

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwal Thank you for the reminder, I just added it in the spring configuration, but it still didn't work.

Comment: And have you wrapped your datasource under transactionManager? Annotation way:[link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) XML way: [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-strategies)

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwal Yes, I think you mean `<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"><property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" /></bean>`, I have it in the spring configuration. In fact, it worked perfectly in the programmatic way, I mean, using `PlatformTransactionManager`. But it doesn't work with `@Transactional`, I don't know why.

Comment: Than most probably you have this also: `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />` .You don't need @EnableTransactionManagement then.

Comment: Make the method public and enable class based proxies.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, Making the method public worked!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @M.Deinum metioned, I have to make the method where `@Transactional` applied public, in other words, I have to change

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
void insert1() {
    TestModel testModel = new TestModel(1, "title1", "content1");
    mapper.insert(testModel);
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

to

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void insert1() {
    TestModel testModel = new TestModel(1, "title1", "content1");
    mapper.insert(testModel);
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

The reason is written in the spring documentation.

> Method visibility and @Transactional
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation, no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.

Comment: Propagation REQUIRED is default

Comment: Why not to use AspectJ?

Comment: Why it's there is no warning for this?