# Spring/MyBatis transactional rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

I tried to use Spring's transaction manager with MyBatis mapper like the following in an implementation of a service

```
@Service("myService")
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService
{
    @Autowired
    private MyMapper myMapper;

    @Transactional(
            value = "transactionManager",
            propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,
            rollbackFor={Exception.class}
    )
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        myMapper.do1();
        myMapper.do2();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

where MyMapper is mapped by MyBatis.
My actual code is a bit different from this, but I've modified it to resemble [How to use @Transactional annotation in mybatis-spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009873/how-to-use-transactional-annotation-in-mybatis-spring).
The service is used in the following manner in controller class.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @GetMapping(value = {"/some/url"})
    public String someMethod(){
        /*
        some code
        */

        myService.doStuff(); // this line is not wrapped in try/catch block

        /*
        some code
        */

    return "myjsppage";
    }
}
```

From what I gather, changes to DB in do1() and do2() should be rolled back, but they persist for some reason. What am I missing? Here's my xml config

```
<mybatis:scan base-package="com.mydomain.mapper" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydomain" />
    <property name="username" value="uuuuuu" />
    <property name="password" value="pppppp" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.mydomain.model"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml"/>
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/mydomain/mapper/*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.mydomain.mapper" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring @Transactional by default rollback on the unchecked/runtime exception.
The attribute rollbackFor must be used only when you are targeting a particular checked exception/customized one

In your case remove the attribute rollbackFor and check the behaviour

Comment: @codemonkey_86531 Is there any explicit queries being interacted between those two operation outside of the spring context? Also, what DB driver you are using. This is just for my information

Comment: (1) No, not in the service (2)just plain old mysql JDBC

Answer (score 0):

by default `@Transaction` use 
`propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED` in that way you must try using:

`@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)`

It will works.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Ok, I've got it working now. I tried many things that didn't work, but cleaning solution and remaking deployable did the trick (?). Why would that be the case, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enable transaction management explicitly in Spring. You may enable annotation driven transaction management by add config below to your spirng configuration file

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```